# How to get an integer as user input in SML

Tags: smlnj

> I'm trying to get a number from a user. That number is then used to
>   call another function `randomList(n)` which takes the given number and
>   uses it. I keep getting the error `exception option`. I've read that
>   adding SOME to the variable declaration or valOf can fix this issue,
>   but it is not working for me. What do I need to change?

```
fun getNumber() = 
print "Please enter the number of integers: ";
let
    val str = valOf (TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn)
    val i : int = valOf (Int.fromString str)
    in 
    randomList(i)
end;
getNumber();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `fun getNumber()` only encompasses the `print` statement on the following line. You need to enclose the `print` and the `let` within parenthesis if you want them to both be a part of `getNumber()`.

For example, the following code compiles and echos the input integer that is passed in via `stdin`:

```
fun getNumber() = (
print "Please enter the number of integers: ";
let
    val str = valOf (TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn)
    val i : int = valOf (Int.fromString str)
in
    print(Int.toString(i))
end
);
getNumber();
```

Comment: When running your code I get the error: `Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]                                                                  
  operator: unit                                                                                                        
  in expression:(print "Please enter the number of integers: ";                                                                                  
     let val <pat> = <exp>                                                                                                           
         val <pat> = <exp> i`

Comment: I also tried to add a `;` and the end of the function parenthesis but that then gives me the error `exception Option` again

Comment: Yes, the `;` was missing at the end of the function parens.

Comment: `exception Option` is raised when you try to `valOf` an `Option` type that's equal to `None`. This could happen if the user input is empty or if `Int.fromString` cannot parse the input string as an integer.

Comment: If you want to have more robust error handling, you should match on the output of `TextIO.inputLine` for `None` or `Some(s)` to catch and ignore `EOF`s.

Comment: I'm running these functions online on tutorialspoint execute sml/nj because I have a problem when I downloaded the compiler from smlnj.org. Could running this code online be causing this problem? Because I never get a prompt to enter anything. It just goes straight to an error.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. The online execution engine apparently does not provide a way to get user input from stdin, so every read from stdin returns `EOF` and therefore `None`. See the documentation on TextIO.inputLine: http://sml-family.org/Basis/text-io.html#SIG:TEXT_IO.inputLine:VAL

Comment: Ah ok. Well thank you for the help. I trust that it works and will do it on a working download of SML. Thanks